# Higher CCA in batteries in warmer climates

Tags: electrical, battery, cold-start

If a battery with a higher CCA capacity is used in a warmer climate, would it effect the battery's performance in the longer run?

Comment: In a warmer climate, it's CA (and not CCA) that you want to go by.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, for the better. In warmer conditions the battery will have even an easier time delivering current and it won't go as deep into its reserves.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically it should last slightly longer. Just plugging in numbers as a simple reference, say a 1000CCA battery degraded 10% per year. After 5 years the battery could supply about 590 amps. If the smaller battery started at 750 amps, after 5 years if it degraded at the same rate it could supply about 440 amps. If your particular vehicle required a 500 amp battery the larger battery would be sufficient after 5 years. The smaller battery would not have the reserve capacity needed and need replacement. But if you factor in the added cost of the battery, how long you intend to keep the vehicle, along with the reduced mileage due to the extra weight, the larger battery may not make economic sense.